# How can I pass table row data to another component in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I created new reactjs application, now I got data from API and displayed table but I need edit row next page. I have passed particular row data but all data passed, I need selected row data only want to display another page. could you please solve this issue. see my code below.

This is edit option code:

```
{
    name:'Action',
    cell:(row)=>(<p className='actions'><span onClick={()=>navigateToConfirmed(row)}><FaPencilAlt/></span><span><FaTrashAlt/></span></p>),
    sortable: true
  },
```

accounts.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"; 
import {Card, Col, OverlayTrigger, Row, Tooltip, Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import DataTable from 'react-data-table-component';
import DataTableExtensions from 'react-data-table-component-extensions';
import 'react-data-table-component-extensions/dist/index.css'; 
import {Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { FaPencilAlt, FaTrashAlt, FaPlus} from "react-icons/fa";
const Accounts = (props) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();   
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [filtername, setfiltername] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios("https://rwood.znapay.in:5001/all/account/datas")
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data);
        setfiltername(res.data);
        console.log(res.data)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
  const columns=[
  {
    name:'Account Name',
    selector:(row)=>row.account_name,
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    name:'Account Number',
    selector:(row)=>row.account_number,
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    name:'Account Owner',
    selector:(row)=>row.account_owner,
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    name:'Annual Revenue',
    selector:(row)=>row.annual_revenue,
    sortable: true
  },{
    name:'Billing Address',
    selector:(row)=>row.billing_address,
    sortable: true
  },{
    name:'Fax',
    selector:(row)=>row.fax,
    sortable: true
  },
  {
    name:'Action',
    cell:(row)=>(<p className='actions'><span onClick={()=>navigateToConfirmed(row)}><FaPencilAlt/></span><span><FaTrashAlt/></span></p>),
    sortable: true
  },
  ]
  const navigateToConfirmed= (row) =>{
    navigate(`/accountedit`, { state: row}); // here we will redirect user and send your data into state
 }

  return (
    <>
    <div className="page-header">
      <div>
        <h2 className="main-content-title tx-24 mg-b-5">Account List</h2>
        <ol className="breadcrumb"> 
          <li className="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Dashboard / Account</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      <div className="d-flex">
        <div className="justify-content-center">
        
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary my-2 btn-icon-text">
           <Link to='/account/addaccount'> <i className="fe fe-download-cloud me-2"></i><FaPlus/> Add Account</Link>
          </button>
          
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
    {/* <div className='bread'> Add Account</Link></div> */}
    <div className=" tasks">
    
             <DataTable
              columns={columns} 
              data={data} 
              pagination
              persistTableHead
             highlightOnHover
             action
             subHeader 
          />
                     
                  </div>
                  </>
  );
}

export default Accounts;
```

accountedit.js

```
import { useLocation} from "react-router-dom";

export default function Accountedit(){
    const {state} = useLocation();
    console.log(state)
return(
    <></>
)
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a working demo (CodeSandbox or Stackblitz,...) for easier debugging? Cause I saw that's your code seemed to correct, not sure where's the issue came from.

Comment: Hi haptn, (CodeSandbox or Stackblitz,...)  not working see my edit option code above how to send particular row data in accountedit.js component, but sent got full data in accountedit.js, but need selected row only.

Answer (score 0):

So if I have understood correctly, you are trying to link a row to another page that will fetch the ID from url.
You can make use of

> "onRowClicked"

property for DataTable Component, for eg:

```
 <DataTable  columns={columns} data={data} customStyles={customStyles} selectableRows pagination onRowClicked={handleRowClick} />
```

and create a function to handle that click,

```
const handleRowClick = async(e) => {
   console.log(e) // outputs the row data in key:value pair object. 
   router.push(`account?id=${e.id}`) // your redirection method. 
}
```

Hope that solves your problem.
Thanks.